# awk delete all lines not containing substring using if condition

Tags: shell, awk

I want to delete lines where the first column does not contain the substring 'cat'.
So if string in col 1 is 'caterpillar', i want to keep it.

```
awk -F"," '{if($1 != cat) ... }' file.csv
```

How can i go about doing it?

Comment: You have to start posting sample input and expected output if you want people to take an interest in helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to delete lines where the first column does not contain the substring 'cat'

That can be taken care by this awk:

```
awk -F, '!index($1, "cat")' file.csv
```

If that doesn't work then I would suggest you to provide your sample input and expected output in question.

Answer (score 1):

This awk does the job too

`awk -F, '$1 ~ /cat/{print}' file.csv`

**Explanation**

`-F` : "Delimiter"

`$1 ~ /cat/` : match pattern cat in field 1

`{print}` : print

Answer (score 1):

A shorter command is:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ "cat"' file.csv
```

`-F` is the field delimiter: (,)

`$1 ~ "cat"` is a (not anchored) regular expression match, match at any position.

As no action has been given, the default: {print} is assumed by awk.